# Batch script with findstr & "line to long"

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using a solution found on StackOverflow some days ago:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Line number of the delimiter line:
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^xxyyzz" "Input.bin"') do set "lines=%%a"
echo %lines%

REM Extract the part of the Input.bin following the delimiter line:
< "Input.bin" (

   REM Pass thru the first lines:
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%lines%) do set /P "="

   REM Copy the rest to output bin:
   findstr "^"

) > Output.bin
```

This is working fine, but with some files I get the error messages **"Line ... too long"**. I know that this problem is associated to **piping**. I also found the tip:

"The line too long error only happens when FINDSTR reads the input via redirection or a pipe. **That error goes away if you pass the name (path) of the file directly to FINDSTR.**"

How my script should be adapted (according to the above tip) to overcome this problem?

Comment: Of course, I would appreciate it if someone told me that this is basically impossible...

Comment: Considerign that there exist regular expressions which _crash_ findstr, I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: OK, grawity, but my question addresses mainly the basic usage/syntax options of for & findstr (which I am unable to understand...)

Comment: just use powershell's [select-string](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6)